# Returning an enum ivar causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, exc-bad-access

I'm writing a game where a MainGameplay class keeps track of whose turn it is by setting an ivar to an enum value:

```
typedef enum {
  GAME_NOT_STARTED,
  PLAYER_1_TO_MOVE,
  PLAYER_2_TO_MOVE
} WhoseTurnIsIt;
```

Then the GameBoard class checks whether a move attempt is valid, and calls either `turnEnded:(WhoseTurnIsIt)turn` or `reportTurnFailure:(WhoseTurnIsIt)turn` in MainGameplay.m.

I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS as soon as I try to access this returned value back in MainGameplay, in the receiving methods. Seems like I should retain something, but you can't retain an enum. In the debugger the values are there, so I don't understand what's being accessed improperly.

This is the code doing the calling in GameBoard:

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
  CCArray *kids = [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene] children];
  if (!mainScene) { // mainScene is an ivar on each the GameBoard's buttons.
    for (CCScene *s in kids) {
      // this looks crazy because the "main" scene is actually a controlling layer that has as a child the main gameplay layer:
      if ([s isKindOfClass:[ControlLayer class]]) {
        self->mainScene = (MainGameplay *)((ControlLayer *) s).gameLayer;
      }
    }
  }

  if (MOVE_NO_ERROR == [self checkMove:mainScene.turn]) {
    [self setMove:mainScene.turn];
    [mainScene turnEnded:mainScene.turn]; // This line and the next are the ones causing the EXC_BAD_ACCESS
  } else [mainScene reportTurnFailure:mainScene.turn]; // This line too.
}
```

**EDIT** Functions in mainScene being called go like this:

```
-(void) reportTurnFailure:(WhoseTurnIsIt)_turn {
  NSLog(@"MainScene still valid"); // This line works fine
  NSLog(@"Bzzzzzt. Player %@, try again", _turn); // This line crashes BUT _turn shows up with a proper value in the debugger.
}
```

Comment: I should mention that the ivars are all `(nonatomic, retain)` where possible and `(nonatomic, assign)` where they are enum values.

Comment: Please provide the error text from the console. Also what is the code for `turnEnded`. Is `mainScene` valid at that point?

Comment: Yep @CocoaFu, I can execute lines of code (i.e. `NSLog(@"MainScene still valid");` just fine within mainScene until I try to access a returned value. The thing is, when I mouse over the value in the debugger it appears! (`PLAYER_1_TO_MOVE`)

Comment: Obviously the turn enum ivar does not have a retain problem so the problem must be the class that contains it must be invalid. I always wonder why so many OPs are reluctant to provide the actual error text from the console (rhetorical question that).

Comment: Does mainScene.turn ever get initialised?

Comment: @CocoaFu Not reluctant, it's just that no console text happens on the EXC_BAD_ACCESS, gdb just goes to the lines I mention.

Comment: OK here is the problem with no error messages: There is not error message in the console. I filed a bug report with apple about that:10772009. But the error message in the code is instructive since it will show an address in the error message that is the value of the argument (_turn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_turn` is not an object, but the `%@` format specifier says that the argument is an object. Use `%i` instead.

```
-(void) reportTurnFailure:(WhoseTurnIsIt)_turn {
  NSLog(@"MainScene still valid"); // This line works fine
  NSLog(@"Bzzzzzt. Player %i, try again", _turn); // This line crashes BUT _turn shows up with a proper value in the debugger.
}
```

Comment: Of course! Thank you so much. (Sigh, I wish XCode would give warnings for mismatched NSLogs... this happens reliably a couple times a year for me and it's always a hair-puller.)

Comment: @ickydog Yeah, true! However, I sometimes get a warning (signed vs unsigned integers, 32 vs 64 bit integers etc), but it seems that %@ just takes everything one throws at it =/